# Using Wt::Dbo cause MySQL prepared statement leak

Tags: mysql, c++11, wt, dbo

I have a project that is using `Wt::Dbo` as object relational database management with MySQL. Since about a week I've remarked a leak in database prepared statement. Previously this project was using SQLite.

I tried different `flush()` without success and can't figure out exactly what is causing this leak, but for sure when prepared statements grow at a certain point, MySQL stop answering.

Here is how I monitor the leaked prepared statement :

```
$ mysql -uroot -p -e "SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE '%prepare%';" | grep stmt_count
Enter password: 
Prepared_stmt_count 260
```

The leaked statement are cleared when program is restarted.

All database operations are centralized inside a class called `DataBase`, here are some functions that are known to leak :

**DataBase::initialize()**

```
void DataBase::initialize(void)
{
    m_oMutex.lock();

    if(!m_bInitialized)
    {
        m_bInitialized = true;

        try
        {
            m_oSessionConfigurations.setConnection(*new Wt::Dbo::backend::Sqlite3("databases/configuration.db"));
            m_oSessionConfigurations.mapClass<InformationSite>("informationsite");

            m_oSessionConfigurations.createTables();
        }
        catch(std::exception &e)
        {
            ajouterLog("error",std::string("DataBase::initialize() : ") + e.what());
        }

        try
        {
            #if defined(DATABASE_TYPE_SQLITE)
                Wt::Dbo::backend::Sqlite3 *pBackend = new Wt::Dbo::backend::Sqlite3("databases/dataBase.db");
            #elif defined(DATABASE_TYPE_MYSQL)
                Wt::Dbo::backend::MySQL *pBackend;

                try
                {
                    pBackend = new Wt::Dbo::backend::MySQL(DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD,"localhost");
                }
                catch(Wt::Dbo::Exception &e)
                {
                    ajouterLog("error",std::string("DataBase::initialize() : ") + e.what());

                    // If MySQL is not available, this cause issue to program until restart.
                    exit(1);
                }
            #endif

            pBackend->setProperty("show-queries","true");

            m_oSession.setConnection(*pBackend);

            m_oSession.setFlushMode(Wt::Dbo::FlushMode::Auto);

            m_oSession.mapClass<RFNode>("rfnode");
            m_oSession.mapClass<NodeMeasure>("nodemeasure");

            // Override the default InnoDB from Wt, MyISAM is easier to repair in case of hardware failure with database corruption
            #if defined(DATABASE_TYPE_MYSQL)
                try
                {
                    Wt::Dbo::Transaction oTransaction(m_oSession);

                    m_oSession.execute("SET default_storage_engine=MYISAM;");

                    oTransaction.commit();
                }
                catch(Wt::Dbo::Exception &e)
                {
                    ajouterLog("error",std::string("DataBase::initialize() : ") + e.what());
                }
            #endif

            m_oSession.createTables();
        }
        catch(Wt::Dbo::Exception &e)
        {
            ajouterLog("error",std::string("DataBase::initialize() : ") + e.what());
        }
    }

    m_oMutex.unlock();
}
```

**DataBase::addNodeMeasure()**

```
void DataBase::addNodeMeasure(NodeMeasure *p_pItem)
{
    m_oMutex.lock();

    try
    {
        Wt::Dbo::Transaction oTransaction(m_oSession);

        Wt::Dbo::ptr<NodeMeasure> oItem = m_oSession.add(p_pItem);

        oItem.flush();

        oTransaction.commit();
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        ajouterLog("error",std::string("Exception DataBase::addNodeMeasure() : ") + e.what());
    }

    m_oMutex.unlock();

    printPreparedStatementCount("DataBase::addNodeMeasure()");
}
```

**DataBase::updateNode()**

```
void DataBase::updateNode(RFNode *p_pItem)
{
    printPreparedStatementCount("DataBase::updateNode() Before");

    m_oMutex.lock();

    try
    {
        Wt::Dbo::Transaction oTransaction(m_oSession);

        Wt::Dbo::ptr<RFNode> oItem = m_oSession.find<RFNode>().where("mac = ?").bind(p_pItem->mac);

        oItem.modify()->zone                    = p_pItem->zone;
        oItem.modify()->subZone                 = p_pItem->subZone;
        oItem.modify()->unit                    = p_pItem->unit;
        oItem.modify()->pwm                     = p_pItem->pwm;
        oItem.modify()->led                     = p_pItem->led;
        oItem.modify()->network                 = p_pItem->network;
        oItem.modify()->lastContact             = p_pItem->lastContact;
        oItem.modify()->ioConfiguration         = p_pItem->ioConfiguration;
        oItem.modify()->networkAddress          = p_pItem->networkAddress;
        oItem.modify()->type                    = p_pItem->type;
        oItem.modify()->functionality           = p_pItem->functionality;
        oItem.modify()->transmitPowerLevel      = p_pItem->transmitPowerLevel;
        oItem.modify()->lastNetworkRoute        = p_pItem->lastNetworkRoute;
        oItem.modify()->lastNetworkJumpsCount   = p_pItem->lastNetworkJumpsCount;
        oItem.modify()->lastRequestDuration     = p_pItem->lastRequestDuration;
        oItem.modify()->hardwareVersion         = p_pItem->hardwareVersion;
        oItem.modify()->softwareVersion         = p_pItem->softwareVersion;

        oItem.flush();

        oTransaction.commit();
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        ajouterLog("error",std::string("Exception DataBase::updateNode() : ") + e.what());
    }

    m_oMutex.unlock();

    printPreparedStatementCount("DataBase::updateNode() After");
}
```

**DataBase::getNodeMeasures()**

```
std::vector<NodeMeasure> DataBase::getNodeMeasures(std::string p_sMAC, int p_nType, Wt::WDateTime p_oStartDate, Wt::WDateTime p_oEndDate, std::string p_sOrder, int p_nLimit)
{
    std::vector<NodeMeasure> lNodeMeasures;

    m_oMutex.lock();

    try
    {
        Wt::Dbo::Transaction oTransaction(m_oSession);

        std::string sWhereClause = "", sOrderClause = "";

        if(!p_sMAC.empty())
        {
            if(!sWhereClause.empty())
            {
                sWhereClause += " AND ";
            }

            sWhereClause += "mac = '" + p_sMAC + "'";
        }

        if(p_nType != -1)
        {
            if(!sWhereClause.empty())
            {
                sWhereClause += " AND ";
            }

            sWhereClause += "type = " + std::to_string(p_nType);
        }

        if(p_oStartDate.isValid())
        {
            if(!sWhereClause.empty())
            {
                sWhereClause += " AND ";
            }

            // When not using type, we usually want nodes measures (not external temperature), so we want to find them using batchDate instead of date
            sWhereClause += (p_nType != -1 ? "date" : "batchDate");
            sWhereClause += " >= '";
            sWhereClause += p_oStartDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").toUTF8();
            sWhereClause += "'";
        }

        if(p_oEndDate.isValid())
        {
            if(!sWhereClause.empty())
            {
                sWhereClause += " AND ";
            }

            // When not using type, we usually want nodes measures (not external temperature), so we want to find them using batchDate instead of date
            sWhereClause += (p_nType != -1 ? "date" : "batchDate");
            sWhereClause += " <= '";
            // Add one second because SQLite have microseconds, and we must include results no matter microseconds field
            sWhereClause += p_oEndDate.addSecs(1).toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").toUTF8();
            sWhereClause += "'";
        }

        if(!p_sOrder.empty())
        {
            sOrderClause = " ORDER BY " + p_sOrder;
        }

        std::string sQuery = "";

        if(!sWhereClause.empty())
        {
            sQuery += " WHERE ";
            sQuery += sWhereClause;
        }

        if(!sOrderClause.empty())
        {
            sQuery += sOrderClause;
        }

        //std::cout << "**************************************************************************" << std::endl;
        //std::cout << sQuery << std::endl;
        //Wt::WDateTime oStart = Wt::WDateTime::currentDateTime();

        if(Configuration::getParameter(Configuration::PARAMETER_DEBUG).getBooleanValue())
        {
            ajouterLog("debug","DataBase::getNodeMeasures() " + sQuery);
        }

        // TEST : find vs query
        Wt::Dbo::collection<Wt::Dbo::ptr<NodeMeasure>> lMeasures = m_oSession.find<NodeMeasure>(sQuery).limit(p_nLimit).resultList();

        // TODO : Get it cleaner... can't use Wt::Dbo::ptr outside transaction.
        for(Wt::Dbo::collection<Wt::Dbo::ptr<NodeMeasure>>::const_iterator pMeasure = lMeasures.begin();pMeasure != lMeasures.end();pMeasure++)
        {
            lNodeMeasures.push_back(
                    NodeMeasure(
                            (*pMeasure)->mac,
                            (*pMeasure)->type,
                            (*pMeasure)->date,
                            (*pMeasure)->batchDate,
                            (*pMeasure)->value
                    )
            );

            (*pMeasure).flush();
        }

        //lNodeMeasures = m_oSession.find<NodeMeasure>(sQuery).limit(p_nLimit).resultList();

        //std::cout << "Result : " << lNodeMeasures.size() << " in " << oStart.secsTo(Wt::WDateTime::currentDateTime()) << "s" << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "**************************************************************************" << std::endl;

        oTransaction.commit();
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        ajouterLog("error",std::string("Exception DataBase::getNodeMeasures() : ") + e.what());
    }

    m_oMutex.unlock();

    printPreparedStatementCount("DataBase::getNodeMeasures()");

    return lNodeMeasures;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the size of the statements grow out of control? Wt::Dbo caches all statements in the MySQL SqlConnection object, and clears them upon destruction. Since applications often use a connection pool of e.g. size 10, the amount of prepared statements is often a multiple of the amount of statements you use.

Since you seem to be composing your statements as ascii text rather than to use parameter binding, you may indeed end up with a lot of statements in your cache.

Dbo supports this type of code style:

```
    auto measuresQuery = m_oSession.find<NodeMeasure>(sQuery).limit(p_nLimit);
    if(!p_sMAC.empty())
    {
        measureQuery.where("mac = ?").bind(p_sMAC);
    }

    if(p_nType != -1)
    {
        measureQuery.where("type = ?").bind(std::to_string(p_nType));
    }
    if(p_oStartDate.isValid())
    {
        // When not using type, we usually want nodes measures (not external temperature), so we want to find them using batchDate instead of date
        measureQuery.where(p_nType != -1 ? "date >= ?" : "batchDate >= ?").bind(p_oStartData);
    }
    if(!p_sOrder.empty())
    {
        measureQuery.orderBy(p_sOrder);
    }

    Wt::Dbo::collection<Wt::Dbo::ptr<NodeMeasure>> lMeasures = measureQuery.resultList();
```

This will yield a smaller amount of prepared statements, and in my opinion shorter, clearer, and more secure code.

Comment: Actually I use only one connection, it lives from the beginning of the application until crash or reboot, 24/7. Statements can grow until MySQL doesn't want to respond properly (about 5000-10000). Is there a way to disable this cache? I've never see any other framework doing that!

Comment: Regarding where and bind, I was using that long time ago but didn't work as expected, I'll give it another try.

Comment: The cache cannot be disabled. There's a protected method to clear the cache (clearStatementCahce()) in MySqlConnection, but I don't think that's the right answer to this problem. I can only recommend to really use prepared statements and bind parameters. Your code will be more performant (the sql server optimizes each reused query only once), and more importantly, secured against SQL injections, which is one of the most important security flaws in web applications.

Comment: I agree for security, but since no parameters comes from forms or URL or anything (mostly automated processing) that was not a problem. I modified most of the hardcoded queries and it leak less for now. Testing on another system!